# Only loopback in /etc/network/interfaces - But internet works?

Tags: 12.10, networking

I just looked in `/etc/network/interfaces`, for the sake of learning Ubuntu better than before.

What I'm wondering is. Why does it look like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Why is my eth0, and wlan0 not in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those are managed by NetworkManager, which does not care about the interfaces file. Its configuration is stored in gconf, not in a form easily editable from the command line.

Comment: Is NetworkManager editable in a textfile, or is it only editable by GUI?

Comment: It is editable in a text file, for example with gedit or vim.

Comment: @chili555 oh really? Tell us more please :)

Comment: If you wish to edit /etc/network/interfaces, which is not recommended if you are using Network Manager, simply do: gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces.Make your changes, save and close gedit. For the old school among us, do: sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces. Make your changes, save and close with :wq.

Comment: That's not the NetworkManager config at all. Please read questions/answers/comments carefully before responding. You had me all excited about being able to quickly edit NetworkManager config and now I'm disappointed :-)

Comment: Sorry. Like Tina Turner, I did it fast and rough. What would you like to edit in NM? Most elements are in conf files.